# What is the_permalink() on a category page?

Tags: theme-development

When I echo get_permalink() in a function that's called from archive.php, it reflects the permalink of the last post that's assigned to the category.

How can I echo the permalink of the category page instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
echo get_category_link( get_queried_object() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go mate:

```
single_cat_title();
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_post_title